# How do I Sort/OrderBy IList<Int32>

Tags: linq

I'm trying Sort on IList, I have tried different approach but none works

here is what my code looks like:

```
IList<IWebElement> listCountIdsUi = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("table#ct_ tr td:nth-of-type(1)"));

List<Int32> ui = new List<Int32>();

foreach (IWebElement option in listCountIdsUi)
{
    if (!option.Text.ToString().StartsWith("Page"))
    {
        ui.Add(Convert.ToInt32(option.Text));
    }
}
```

the only way I able to figured out is working with `ArrayList`

```
 ArrayList al = new ArrayList(ui);
 al.Sort();
```

is not possible using IList ?

Comment: I looks like you're randomly changing your code until you find something that seems to work. Stop. Learn what each method actually does and *then* write your code.

Comment: what random code you talking about?

Comment: The three versions that you tried. For example `SequenceEqual()` or `CaseInsensitiveComparer()` don't seem to make any sense here. And it looks like you don't understand what `OrderBy()` actually does.

Comment: agreed, i did not mean to paste SequenceEqual and CaseInsensitiveComparer code....i have updated my question - thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the `List<T>.Sort` method?

```
ui.Sort((a, b) => a.CompareTo(b));
```

Comment: If `T` implements `IComparable<T>`, you don't need the lambda, `ui.Sort();` will suffice.

Comment: True, bur I was just making sure.

Answer (score 2):

`OrderBy` does NOT modify the underlying collection - it *returns* an `IEnumerable` that gives you the items in the order you ask for.  So you have a few options:

1. Use [`List.Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx), which *does* modify the underlying collection:

   ```
   ui.Sort();
   ```
2. Store the sorted list in a new variable

   ```
   var uiSorted = ui.OrderBy(s => s);
   ```
3. replace the existing reference

   ```
   ui = ui.OrderBy(s => s).ToList();
   ```

Answer (score 0):

`var uiOrdered = ui.OrderBy(s => s).ToList()` should be all you need to do.

Comment: Why use OrderBy when List<T> provides you with a better method?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance I wouldn't say it's better, just different. Sometimes `Sort()` is the way to go, sometimes `OrderBy()` is more appropriate.

Comment: @svick You're right, what I meant to say was that `Sort` is more appropiate here.